# Is it possible to inspect the Request Headers when using Cake\Http\Client?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I am trying to login to a website from a Command. I would like to inspect what headers are sent to the site so that I can compare them with what the browser sends. I am *ASSuming* the Cake Http Client will send some headers by default, I want view these.

I have been able to see the response headers via `$this->Client->get($url)->getHeaders()`, but have found no way to see what headers are sent.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but from looking at the code it seems that maybe just `$this->Client->getHeaders()` might work?

Comment: Does not work: `2023-06-28 19:49:45 error: [Error] Call to undefined method Cake\Http\Client::getHeaders()`

Comment: What's your exact CakePHP version (last line in lib/Cake/VERSION.txt or vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt)?

Comment: The  version is 4.4.10

Comment: Right, the `getHeaders` is on the request object, not the client, and it seems that the request is only ever a temporary internal implementation detail. It looks like you might be able to make your own custom Client, extending the default one, overriding just the `_createRequest` function to call the default and store it in the Client object, and exposing a method to retrieve the headers from that.

Comment: Or if you need this only temporarily during debugging of your code, just throw something into the Cake code that logs the headers when it sends a request, or use `xdebug` to put a breakpoint and inspect the data at that time.